# Why does $P[R\ge 15]= 0.003291$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

R follows a binomial distribution such that $R$~$Bin(24,0.4)$

I don't understand how to get the answer for this. 
From my understanding, $$P[R\ge 15]=P[R=0]+P[R=1]+P[R=2]+P[R=3]+..P[R=15] $$, doing this I don't get 0.003291, I got 0.1142651=not the solution.

The correct answer is 0.003291 but I keep getting the wrong answer. Is the way I did it wrong?

Edit:
Here is the whole question
Red and white chocolate balls are randomly filled into boxes containing a total of 24 balls.
The color of each ball is determined by a random mechanism such that on average 60% of all balls are
black.
(a) Let the random variable R denote the number of red chocolate balls in a box. What is the distribution of R?

R is binomial with parameters n= 24, p=0.4

(b) What is the probability that all chocolate balls in one box have the same color?

P[R = 24] + P[R = 0]= 4.74x$10^{-10}$

(c) How many boxes need to be selected to have a chance of > 90% to have at least one box with at least 13 red chocolate balls?

So I know how to find the number of boxes but it seems I made a mistake at one point, which led me to the wrong answer.

$P[R\ge 15]= 0.003291$ is the correct answer. Why? I don't understand how they got that answer.

Comment: Do you have a typo because with $P[R\ge 15]$ you want to check for values $\ge 15$, but you seem to have the values on the right side being those where $P[R\le 15]$ instead?

Comment: No, no typo, so what I understood was wrong and it was actually for P[R≤15]?

Comment: I don't have much context about what you have or what you're doing, but $P[R\le 15]$ means the probability of $R \le 15$. Assuming $R$ can only take on non-negative integral values, then making this change to your left side should mean it would then match your right side sum.

Comment: Would it be better if I post the whole question properly here?

Comment: @JohnOmielan edited, gn

Answer (score 1):

I find $P(R=0)=0.6^{24}\approx 4.74\cdot 10^{-6}$, much larger than your calculation.  Your equation for $P(R \ge 15)$ has all the wrong terms on the right.  The right side computes $P(R \le 15)$

I find the probability of at least $13$ red balls to be about $0.1143$, which matches your number that you say is $P(R \ge 15)$, but I am computing $P(R \ge 13)$.  If you open $n$ boxes, the chance none of them have at least $13$ red balls is then $(1-0.1143)^n$, so to have $90\%$ chance of at least one having $13$ red balls you solve $(1-0.1143)^n=0.1$ and find $n$ is $19$.

I don't find any $0.003291$ in the binomial distribution here, either point values or cumulative.